# A question in integral convergence

Tags: calculus, limits, improper-integrals

For what real values of $a$ the following integral converges?

$$ \int_0^1 (-\ln{x})^a dx $$

Comment: This is, of course, the famous [Gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do some u-subbing. 
$$\int_0^1 (-\ln(x))^a\, dx = \int_{-\infty}^0 (-\ln(e^x))^a e^x\,dx 
=  \int_0^\infty x^a e^{-x}\, dx. $$
This integral converges provided $a > -1$.

Comment: I thought so, but how do you show that it does not converge for $a<-1$ ?

Comment: The map $x\mapsto x^a$ does not integrate across 0 if $a \le -1$.